# Why the string in unicode form is not equal to its unicode code point value?

Tags: python-3.x, unicode

We can get the string `你`'s unicode code point value:

```
u'你'.encode('unicode-escape')
b'\\u4f60'
```

Why the string in unicode form is not equal to its unicode code point value?

```
u'你'  ==  u'\x4f\x60'
False
u'你'  ==  u'\\u4f60'
False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is, but your comparison strings are not correct to compare. The first one is two separate characters of a single byte, and the second one has the backslash escaped, meaning that it is the literal 6 characters `\u4f60`.

```py
u'你' == u"\u4f60"
True
```

The encoded byte string has the two backslashes since the encoding escapes it, making it not equivalent even if turned back into a string unless you decode it with `unicode-escape` as well.

Side note, the `u` is default in python 3.